# Is there anyway to create a friendly URL for AWS Elasticsearch domain url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, endpoint, opensearch

I tried creating a Route 53 alias record but that didn't work.

Comment: A CNAME mapping should work. its working for me.

Comment: Is it that you are not able to load kibana or are you not able to push logs?

Comment: @Shibashis the problem with a CNAME is that you still need the `_plugin/kibana` path.

Comment: Another problem with CNAME is that if using SSL, the certificate won't match the domain. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156894/route53-for-aws-elastic-search-domain-gives-certificate-error

Answer (score 6):

It is possible as of November 2020:

> 1. Choose **Edit domain**.
> 2. To add a **Custom endpoint**, select the **Enable custom endpoint** check box.
> 3. For **Custom hostname**, enter your preferred custom endpoint hostname. Your custom endpoint hostname should be a fully qualified domain name (FQDN), such as [www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com) or example.yourdomain.com.
> 4. For **AWS certificate**, choose the SSL certificate that you want to use for your domain.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-customendpoint.html

Answer (score 2):

We don’t support custom SSL certificates, which means that a custom CNAME for an Elasticsearch Service endpoint such as `mycluster.mycompanyname.example` also is not supported.

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-faq.html#faq-dns

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: could you please update the link to the new one: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-faq-technical.html#faq-ssl

Answer (score 1):

It is still **not** possible on September 2020:

> **Can I use a Custom SSL certificate?**
>
> We don’t support custom SSL certificates, which means that a custom CNAME for an Elasticsearch Service endpoint such as mycluster.mycompanyname.com also is not supported.

[source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-faq-technical.html#faq-ssl)

Comment: This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wild card certificate like *.youdomain.com (for subdomain setup) or a domain certificate (e.g yourdomain.com) if you have a domain that you want to point to this cluster in ACM.

***Assuming you are going with a subdomain setup. You can follow similar steps for domain setup.***

While creating the ES cluster select the custom domain option and add Custom hostname as your subdomain (e.g: elasticsearch.yourdomain.com) And for certificate chose wildcard certificate from ACM. Or you can edit your cluster and do the same.

If you have cogito auth for kibana You will need also need to follow these steps:

1. Go to Cognito pool
2. Under App integration > App client settings
3. Update Sign-in and sign-out URLs according to your subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more information to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64731048/11758843) by [yurez's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321108/yurez).

**The following step is also important:**

After you enable a custom endpoint for your OpenSearch Service domain, you must create a CNAME mapping in Amazon Route 53 (or your preferred DNS service provider) to route traffic to the custom endpoint and its subdomains. Create the CNAME from the custom endpoint (the name of the record e.g., example.yourdomain.com) to the auto-generated endpoint (the value of the record e.g., vpc-1b1b1b1b1b1b1b1b1b1b1b1b1.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com). **Without this mapping, your custom endpoint won't work.**

Reference: [Creating a custom endpoint for Amazon OpenSearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-customendpoint.html)

Answer (score -3):

You can use route 53 service of AWS, Create record with CNAME and put value as some friendly name like kibana.logs.com or whatever domain you owned.